# Rounded corners on a gtk window

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to get rounded corners on every corner of a window.
How can I achieve that?

I tried to change my gtk.css in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and I'm getting rounded corners without transparency.

css I used:

```css
.background.csd {
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
.background.maximized, .background.solid-csd {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Picture showing the corners I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej48Z.png)